# admob interstitial kotlin problem Android: Not showing ads

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Are there any problems with my code? Admob interstitial not working.

I tried every step I find on developers.google.com
I successfully applied the banner ads but the problem with interstitial.

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds

class start : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start)


        MobileAds.initialize(this,
                "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")

        mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
        mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
        mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdClosed() {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            }
        }


    }


    fun okok(view: View) {

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
            mInterstitialAd.show()
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.")
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: when you use the function okok?

Comment: also i think that in current situation better solution is first load the interstitial ad, and when user closes the ad then you go startActivity(intent)